# KML file more than 2000 placemarks

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I want to import kml files that contains more than 2000 placemarks into googla map. 
I use google api v3.
I can only show 200 placemarks.
I know that I can use more layers, but I want only one because I have to refresh it weekly and I don't want to split every time.

Thanks for your replays

THIS IS THE CODE:

```
<script>

  var map;
  function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.25,19.5),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    loadKmlLayer(map);

  }

  function loadKmlLayer(map) {
      var ctaLayer2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://.../asdf.kml', {
        suppressInfoWindows: false,
        preserveViewport: false,
        map: map 
    });
}

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a sample KML file that exhibits the problem you can provide?

Comment: Are you using the [Google Maps API v3 KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers)?  Or Google MyPlaces (AKA "My Maps")?  ([MyMaps](https://sites.google.com/site/gmapstips/alternative-to-paging-on-my-maps) breaks the KML into 200 "feature" pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(function() {

```
window.onload = function() {

    // Creating a new map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.10,19.5),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Creating the JSON data
    var json = [
```

DATA HERE LIKE:

{"title" :"City ZIP CODE STREET" , "lat" :47.2876 , "lng" :20.4978 ,"description" :"YOUR DESCRIPTION"},

```
                ]

    // Creating a global infoWindow object that will be reused by all markers
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // Looping through the JSON data
    for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++)
    {
        var data = json[i],
            latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title,
        //  icon: iconimage

        });

        // Creating a closure to retain the correct data, notice how I pass the current data in the loop into the closure (marker, data)
        (function(marker, data) {

            // Attaching a click event to the current marker
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });


        })

        //OnClick event
        (marker, data);

    }
} })();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your KML isn't very complex, you could try rendering it with a third-party KML parser ([geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)), see if that works (or points to the problem you are having with KmlLayer)